# Gimp clone tool not working

Tags: gimp

Gimp version: 2.10.30

OS: Arch Linux

When I try to draw using the clone tool, I just get a message saying "Set a source image first". I'm holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking to select a source, but it's not letting me draw once I select the clone source.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce this problem unfortunately.  Ctrl+click does set the source, and should work. [see example](https://imgur.com/gLjvLSO). I wonder if there is some conflict with your screen recording software?

Comment: Perhaps a tiny selection somewhere? Tried `Select > None`?

Comment: I found post [a post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/what-happened-to-gimp-clone-tool-it-stopped-working-for-me-4175702136-print/page2.html) from a Linux user who said they had to use Ctrl+Alt+click. Try that. Might be OS related.

Comment: @BillyKerr it happens without screen recording running (I wasn't screen recording when I first discovered the issue)

Comment: @BillyKerr - You're right, `Ctrl + Alt` was the right key combo. Not sure why that changed! Thanks for the info.

Comment: It hasn't changed. It's an OS thing, something to do with some Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Billy Kerr I also have the same problem on Ubuntu with Gimp 2.10.30 and using Cnt+Alt+click works there as well. So I guess it is a problem with Linux and Gimp. So if you have a problem on Linux try Cnt+Alt+click to set the source.